# Is 'what' both relative adjective and relative pronoun?

Tags: relative-clauses

> The body was no longer twitching. The skin had taken on a milky bluish
>   tinge. The corner of the mouth seemed to have stopped bleeding, and
>   **what** little blood **was** still visible now **appeared** very slightly darker
>   and thicker, although the red, green and amber bulbs of the footlights
>   might be influencing my color perception.
>   [*The Weed That Strings the
>   Hangman's Bag*]

There are two verbs after what-phrase. In this case, (1) is relative pronoun ‘that’ omitted after blood, or (2) does ‘what’ take two roles of a relative adjective and relative pronoun?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best classification of **what** in this usage is as a **determiner**:

**what**:  *determiner*

...

2.
a.  the (person, thing, persons, or things) that: *we photographed what animals we could see*

...

Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003

*what little blood was still visible* is a noun clause used here as subject; it may be paraphrased *the small amount of blood that was still visible*, or *such traces of blood as were still visible*. This what-structure does not take *that*.

*Little* is a quantifier here rather than the categorially polysemic adjective.

Comment: In the OP's provided sentence, it'd be a _relative_ determiner, yes?

Comment: Sorry about the delay - it's hard to find analyses. In _we photographed those animals_, those would be a demonstrative determiner (with a deictic - extra-textual pragmatic - role). In _we photographed those animals that we could see_ and _we photographed what animals we could see_, I think you must be right - there is an adjective clause following, so the term **relative** applies. So, some but not all determiners have a syntactic role.

Comment: At http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners , the subclass is illustrated: **Relative determiners**: _which_ (quite formal, as in He acquired two dogs and three cats, which animals were then...); also _whichever_ and _whatever_ (which are of the type that form clauses with no antecedent: I'll take whatever money they've got). Seems correct to me. And, at http://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Relative_determiners : Pages in category "Relative determiners"

The following 4 pages are in this category, out of 4 total.
W
**what
whatever
which
whichever**

Answer (score 3):

*What* is here an adjective, meaning in the OED’s, definition 8, *that (or those) . . . which (or who); such . . . as; often expressing quantity, So much (or many) . . .as*.

One of eight citations illustrating the use is this, from John Ruskin: ‘I will take **what** indulgence the . . . reader will give me’.

Answer (score 3):

Neither term is correct for *what*. *What* (like how) is a *Wh*-word that **can't** be used as a [relative clause marker](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html). For example, the following are all relative clauses marked with *Wh*-words; the last two are ungrammatical -- in practice, we use *that* instead of *how* to mark relatives.

- *the man who did it*
- *the place where they did it*
- *the day when they did it*
- *the reason why they did it*
- *the thing which they did*
- *the way that they did it*
- **the thing what they did*
- **the way how they did it*

As for the difference between "relative adjective" and "relative pronoun", pay no attention; relative markers can function as both. In fact, pay no attention to what "Part of Speech" a word is said to be; the citations are wrong, they're not using the correct list anyway, and, in the first place, most English words belong to several different categories.

However, since this is **not** a relative clause, this must be a different *what*. It is in fact the *Wh*-word that introduces an [embedded question subject complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

- *what little blood was still visible*

which is a noun clause that is the subject of *appeared* in the quotation.

Embedded question complements are finite (they require a tensed verb like *was*), and they **must** begin with a *Wh*-word (there is in fact a special *Wh*-word *whether*, which is used only in embedded questions to mark an embedded *Yes/No* question).

- *Will she be here?*
- *I don't know whether she will be here.*
- *Whether she will be here is something no one knows.*

This kind of embedded question refers to the answer to the question, whether it's known or not:

- *What they did was terrible.* = The answer to "what did they do?" is terrible.
- *What they did is unknown.* = The answer to "what did they do?" is unknown.

And, to get finally to the point, in this case it's a special use of *what*, quantifying the amount of blood and indicating its degree.

- *what little blood was visible* = The answer to "what amount of blood was visible" is "little".

Other synonymous constructions that can be substituted in the same context include

- *the small amount of blood that was visible*
- *the small amount of visible blood*
- *what visible blood there was*
- *what blood there was (that was) visible*

> **Afterthought**
>   I have since come to believe that there is no semantactic difference between "headless relative clauses" and "embedded question clauses".
>
> Whatever distinction there may be becomes ever less pronounced the more the clauses are dismembered, especially when they reach skeletal infinitives like *What to do* or *How to do it*. I just call them all "*Wh*-clauses" any more.

Comment: So, is _relative determiner_ also inaccurate? Isn't "what little blood" referring to the (quantity of) _bleeding_ earlier in the sentence?

Comment: Relative clauses are not involved in the question, so "relative" anything is inaccurate. If you're not referring to relative clauses, don't use the word _relative_; _comparative_ is the term that refers to comparisons like this.

Comment: relative [ˈrɛlətɪv]
adj

6. (Linguistics / Grammar) Grammar denoting or belonging to a class of words that function as subordinating conjunctions in introducing relative clauses. In English, relative pronouns and determiners include who, which, and that Compare demonstrative [5] interrogative [3]
7. (Linguistics / Grammar) Grammar denoting or relating to a clause (relative clause) that modifies a noun or pronoun occurring earlier in the sentence

Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003

Comment: I think the adjectival nature of the those-structures is being referenced by the term _relative_ here: We photographed those animals we could see. (determiner usage of _those_) We photographed animals - those we could see. (pronoun usage of _those_)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: possibly that's the intention. But both definitions of _relative_ that you cite refer to use in relative clauses. The fact that relative clauses usually modify a noun does not change the fact that it's relative clauses, not modification in general, that's being referred to. There are lots of non-relative constructions that modify nouns, too.

Comment: @John Lawler: So you disagree with the views (or at least the terminology) of the staff at 'Oxford Dictionaries'? (It's the sort of thing I often do):  http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/what **what 2** [relative determiner] (referring to the whole of an amount) whatever:
he had been robbed of what little money he had

Comment: This is a syntactic phenomenon, and dictionaries are not involved with grammar. They provide lexical information, and (if they're good) the actual grammatical categories that words belong to; most American dictionaries, for instance, don't give enough information to allow one to decide that _*I ate a bowl of rices_ and _*I ate a bowl of bean_ are both ungrammatical, but that they're both OK if one swaps the plural inflections. If you want grammar, you go to a grammar, not a dictionary.

Comment: We're still in the situation described by a Christian speaker I know: "Do you know why Bible teachers have so many different versions? So they can find one that says exactly what _they_ want to say." Or even worse, since most grammars disagree at various points, we'll be left either confused or adopting a poor interpretation. Or unable to find a version we're satisfied with.

Comment: We don't have to solve the problems of the world like Christians do, and there is no Authority that censors grammatical terminology, so clearly you or anybody else can use any terms you like, for whatever reasons you like. Just don't expect that it's going to be understood by professionals, who have their own terminology and their own habits of usage for it. To a grammarian, unless specially qualified, _relative_ in a technical grammatical term refers to _relative clause_. That's all, really. There are other senses of _relative_, but they're not grammatical.

Comment: Will http://www.docstoc.com/docs/122771064/POSTMODIFICATION-IN-NOUN-PHRASES do as a 'grammar source'? (P2) **nominal relative clauses** ... 7a _What money I have is yours_. (Then the oxforddictionaries.com definition given above follows.)

Comment: Not without authorship and citations, no. It's pretty good about the structure, but it does call these embedded questions "nominal relative clauses", whereas [the syntactic literature](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CQ-DQ-New.pdf) calls them "embedded questions". And these in turn are confusable with "headless relatives" like _Who steals my purse steals trash_, where _who_ comes from something like _He who_.

Comment: One of the biggest differences between embedded questions and relative clauses -- whatever they begin with -- is that Relative Clause Formation operates over variables, whereas embedded questions are cyclic and governed by the matrix verb. See [Rule Typology](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/ross.html). Though there are some circumstances where they merge and one can hardly tell the difference; syntax has a lot of bleed-offs like that between categories.

Comment: Note Afterthought above.