# Can we use 'what' as a relative pronoun in formal English?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, dependent-clause

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> *A stone **what** rolls gathers no moss.*

Comment: No. _What_ is not used as a relative pronoun. There are sociolects that relax this rule, but they are stigmatized. _What_ does occur as a fused relative marker, meaning _that which_; e.g, _What doesn't kill you strengthens you._

Comment: The relative "what" that occurs in fused NPs like "I really liked [what she wrote]" is a pronoun.

Comment: This sounds like Cockney English to me.

Comment: @JohnLawler What *is* used as a relative pronoun, but only with a suppressed antecedent — *With joy beyond what victory bestows.*

Comment: That's the fused relative pronoun that @BillJ and I mentioned above. You can always substitute the phrase _that which_ for this use of _what_. That's why it's called "fused".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is 'what' both relative adjective and relative pronoun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101365/is-what-both-relative-adjective-and-relative-pronoun)